# Instant UPS tracking Number

Tags: php, magento, cart, shopping-cart, ups

I have a client that has a shopping cart. She wants to implement a module that allows the end user to receive a tracking number immediately after purchase.

I am not too sure if this is possible. My concept is that after the store owner ships the purchase, that's when the store owner receives a tracking number that he/she can give to the purchaser. And the purchaser then can start tracking their package.

I guess my question is... "Is it possible to generate a tracking number to give to the purchaser before the store owner even bothers to wrap up the order and send it out.This is so the purchaser can automatically start tracking their purchase and the store owner doesn't have to manually give them a tracking number." ?

I know this would have to require the api. I just need to know if this is possible before I start investing alot of time in trying to build it.

She is using Magento for her shopping cart service.

Comment: Yes that is possible. you can use the UPS API, but it would not generate the tracking number without generating ups label. You can get help from webcollage.wordpress.com

Answer (score 1):

You can use what's called a **tracking reference**.

From UPS:

> When you create a shipment, you can
>   assign a shipment reference that helps
>   you track quickly and with ease. This
>   reference can contain up to 35
>   characters in any combination of
>   letters and numbers

http://www.ups.com/content/us/en/resources/track/check/#Track+by+Reference

UPS will store this reference number in its system so that you can have customers track with that instead. They will need to click Track By Reference in the Track Packages & Freight tab.

Comment: This reference must be passed into the UPS system through Worldship. Also if you are using your UPS Web Account to arrange your shipments, check for the ability to enter the reference number there. On our inventory management system, I pass Worldship both the original Sales Order Number and Invoice Number. The UPS module in Magento is a Rates only system, it doesn't pass this information into the UPS system as its shipment function doesn't actually create a UPS shipment. ShipWorks can be used to pull the orders from Magento, process them and generate the shipping lables/tracking numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's "possible" in that way that everything in software is possible. There's nothing built-in or third party that I know of that would build this functionality into a system though.  <s>My experience with the UPS shipping API says that even if you created a UPS shipment at the time of ordering, there's a non-deterministic delay before the actual shipping code is created</s>. See mention of tracking reference in this thread.

If you want to move forward with this, it means creating **your own** tracking system.  Immediately after generating an order you also generate a unique tracking number, and a tracking URL.  This URL points at your system, and returns a page that lists ou;t any UPS, FedEX, etc tracking numbers that are in the system for that order.  If the order hasn't received its number yet, you list a message like "at source warehouse" instead.

Good luck, ERP and fulfillment integration is always a bear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i think Magento has built-in support for such tracking services. 
Dont remember if it supports UPS but i guess it does.

Otherwise use the UPS Developer API and play around with their web services.

And for the advance tracking number as you require that feature is also implemented in Magento for shipping packages as well as order tracking etc...

- PS: I observed these in Magento 1.4+

Answer (score 0):

You can get bundles of shipping forms with fields such as your business name, address, account etc that are prefilled. These bundles also have sequenced tracking numbers.

You would have to get these bundles and upon receiving them enter the starting number and ending number of the stack into a database. From there the person packing the order must be careful to use the correct form with the order.

Answer (score -1):

If you interface with ShipWorks and set it up with your UPS account, it both creates your UPS shipping label, gets the shipping charge and posts the UPS tracking number back to Magento. Very smooth integration.